# WPF automatically updates from INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

Does WPF framework automatically get the updates from `INotifyPropertyChanged` derived types to the `Bindings` in the UI?

Or do I have to do it manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, it's automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Semi manually,

```
    string _tText;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _tText; }
        set
        {
            _tText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }
```

Here the property changed show call once the property is set with some value. `OnPropertyChanged("Text");`

Comment: this is a call to your view model implementation, not `INotifyPropertyChanged`'s event.

Comment: That way of implementing the interface might be risky. Unless you check whether the new and the old values are actually different, you might end up with an indirect infinite recursion there.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - How raising an event will end up in infinite recursion? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Gusdor: This code block was extended with the above answer... there is the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface and i mentioned that the way where the property changed to be raised.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Might be right, but in WPF, framework itself take care of recursion if same value gets initiated. So it depends of the case where this is going to be used. Unless we have check whether the new value if different before raising the event.

Comment: @RohitVats: Imagine two objects, both of which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Whenever a particular property of one object gets assigned a value, a particular property of the other object is updated (and vice-versa). If none of the objects checks whether the property is actually changing, and just fires `PropertyChanged` all the time, no-one is breaking the loop and you end up with an infinite recursion.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - No it won't. That will be recursion of property setter and in no way an issue of `PropertyChanged` event. Issue you mentioned will fail even in case your class not implementing `INPC`.

Comment: @RohitVats: One `PropertyChanged` event handler sets a property, which in turn invokes another `PropertyChanged` event handler, which then sets the other property, which again invokes the first `PropertyChanged` event handler ... see where the recursion is happening?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: "but in WPF, framework itself take care of recursion" framework binding will take care of it.

Comment: `PropertyChanged` event handler should not set any property at first place. If it's then already we have a bad design in place. You can't code for bad design. It will fail anyhow one or other day.

Comment: @Sankarann: Yes, because it does exactly what I am suggesting; it checks on one side of the binding whether the property value has actually changed. That is no reason to be sloppy on the other side and neglect the check there; an `INotifyPropertyChanged` class should never rely on its subscribers to do the checking as it is something that can be easily implemented in the class itself, based on the principle of defensive programming.

Comment: @RohitVats: Why not? How else do you implement mutual dependencies between property values across various objects (that do not know of each other) outside of the realm where dependency properties are available?

Answer (score 0):

semi-Manually :-)

When you implement "INotifyPropertyChanged" you will implement those methods (which are usually implemented the same)

```
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, e); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
```

After that, when one of your properties has changed, you need to call "RaisePropertyChanged" with the name of the property that changed. usually in the setter of that property

Comment: One does not derive from an interface. One implements an interface. Minor but worth mentioning as c# does _not_ support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Excellent! Fun tip, if you leave the property name string empty, wpf refreshes all binding to that object :D

Comment: With respect to the question, I think your answer should read "automatically" rather than "semi-manually". (The *implementation* of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is (as any implementation, including that of dependency properties) manual, but "getting the updates" from an `INotifyPropertyChanged`-implementing type is just as automatic as getting the updates from a `DependencyObject` with dependency properties.

Comment: For me it is still unclear. If I bind MyOnPropChange(s, args){ OnPropertyChanged(args.Name) } to the PropertyChanged eventHandler, will this automatically update my view on change, without calling "manual" OnPropertyChanged. I am asking because I don't want to add it to every set{} manually